# Select element except for specific child

Tags: jquery, html

My problem is:

I select a div with many children and would like to know how to not select a certain element which is actually a child of that previously selected element.

I already tried the `:not(selectedElement)` selector and the `.not(selectedElement)` selector or api (dont know how it's called). Anyway, I also found someone who asked a similar question which didn't help so I guess the only way to find out what is wrong is to ask here if you have any approaches (I know stackoverflow is not meant to work like that but I seriously sat there many times and couldnt solve it):

HTML:

```
<div class="tablee" style="cursor:/*pointer*/;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="something.php">
                        <img src="1.jpg">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="postcontent">
                    <p class="postusername">
                        <a class="poster" href="something.php">momo</a>
                        <br>
                        some other text
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <imgsrc="1.jpg">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//non-dynamyic
$(".tablee").not($(this).find('a')).click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

So if `tablee` is clicked and not a link within it (within `tablee` element) the next element that comes after `tablee` shall toggle.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what exactly are you trying to acheive? Unselecting all a's except the current? Also try to create a stackoverflow code snippet or a http://jsfiddle.net/ which explains the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your selector is not selecting all the children and attaching the click event to then. The event is only on the actual selector and on click of a child the event is propagating up to the parent.

You have a click event on `.tablee` which you do not want to trigger on the click of any `a` within. In this case have a separate event on `a` with `stopPropagation`:-

```
$(".tablee").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});

$(".tablee a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will then stop any click on `a` bubbling up to `.tablee`.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment

> I´m trying to toggle the next element (the element that comes directly after tablee) when the tablee element is clicked unless those links were not clicked.

Here is a way to ignore the anchors,

```
$(".tablee").click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is("a")){
         $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
});
```

The above `is("a")` checks the current clicked target.

*Why your code didn't work*

```
$(".tablee").not($(this).find('a'))
```

In the above selector `this` refers to the window object and not the `.tablee` element. Also `not()` on the parent `div` would filter the elements with class `.tablee` and not child elements on the `div`.

Comment: sorry i missed one dot in the comment it shoud ve been " links were .not (so in that not api or whatever its called) clicked. Annyways thanks for helping the problem got solved!

Comment: No problem. Glad you found out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is to test the target event element:

```
$('.tablee').on('click', function(e) {
     if (e.target.tagName != 'A') {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).next().slideToggle();
     }
 });
```

Comment: it works but I think the better way to do that is the stop propagation way... anyways thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery .not() will filter a set of results, so put it to the right of the set you want to filter**

Looks like you are thinking of jQuery's .not() select as something that will *preclude* an element from being added to a set of selected items.

Actually, it's a filter to remove elements that are already selected. So, first select the superset, then (to the right of that) place a not to filter out the undesired elements.

A simple example:

```
<ul class="wrapper">
<li class="one">select me</li>
<li class="two">don't select me</li>
<li class="three">select me</li>
</ul>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapper").find('li').not(".two").css("color","blue");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to select only those children that do *not* contain a `<a>` tag, correct?

This would find all the `<a>` tags, but that's not what you want.

```
$('td').find('a')
```

This finds all the `<td>` that *contain* `<a>` tags.

```
$('td').has('a')
```

So, you just need to exclude those

```
$('table').not( $('td').has('a') ).click( function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Not sure if that was the precise element you were looking for, but that's how to find elements that contain certain other elements. In CSS, its

```
td:has(>a)
```

But unfortunately, no browser supports that as of now.